# what is the role of "src" and "url" propery?

Tags: css

While rendering the following code, what is the role of "src" propery?

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: "calibriforh1"; 
    src: local("calibri"), url(calibri.woff); 
}

h1 { font-family: "calibriforh1", arial, sans-serif; }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `src` property is used to identify where the font file is located. It can be defined as `local` and/or via a remote `url`. In this case the definition is specifying that the font `calibri` should be used if it is installed on the users computer. If not it needs to look for the file `calibri.woff` in the css folder.
Check out the [MDN page on Font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

Answer (score 4):

*Info from, and further information available from the links posted below*

The `load()` method of `font-face` which looks like this:

```
interface FontFace {
  attribute DOMString family;
  attribute DOMString style;
  attribute DOMString weight;
  attribute DOMString stretch;
  attribute DOMString unicodeRange;
  attribute DOMString variant;
  attribute DOMString featureSettings;
  readonly attribute FontFaceLoadStatus status;
  Promise<FontFace> load();
  readonly attribute Promise<FontFace> loaded;
};
```

identifies `src` as a slot.  The `src` descriptor is required for the `@font-face` rule to be valid according to spec.  The purpose of it is to define the separation of resources, whereas the subsequent `url` value actually specifies the location of the external resource in which comprises the font files or glyphs.

Specifically..

> The internal [[Urls]] slot of the FontFace object is set to the value of the @font-face rule’s src descriptor, and reflects any changes made to the src descriptor.
>
> ► CSS Font Loading Module Level 3 (s.2.3)

The load() method of FontFace uses CORS-enabled fetch to read the font data specified in the font-face files. For fonts constructed from binary data, or fonts that are already loading or loaded, it does nothing.

When the render client reads the font-face code, it iterates over the `src` references until it finds one it can successfully render.  Subsequent values are then never processed.

For the sake of simplicity, you can compare the relation of `src` and `url` to that of a key value array.

Proper syntax for `src` is

```
<url> [format(<string> #)]? | <font-face-name> ] #
```

### Further:

- [CSS Fonts Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#src-desc)
- [CSS Font Loading Module Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-font-loading/)
- [HTML5 Vocabulary, CORS-enabled fetch](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#cors-enabled-fetch)

Answer (score 0):

It's for searching the user's system for a "calibri" font, and if it does not exist, it will load the font from the server instead.